# ElementCollection and Set<Object>

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Please help me understand, I can not understand why some queries to the database are not obtained.

I do not want to declare the Med field as an entity, because there will only be an enumeration of values. How to properly link tables so that the first query works?

Pet:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Pet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private Boolean found;
    private Boolean help;
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "pet_med", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pet_id"))
    @Column(name = "med")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Med> med;
    private String history;
    private String video;
    private String color;
    private String home;

    @Column(name = "category")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Category category;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;

    @Column(name = "character")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Character character;

    @Column(name = "size")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Size size;

    @Column(name = "wool")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Wool wool;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shelter_id")
    private Shelter shelter;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pet", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<PetPhoto> photos;

    public Pet(
            String name,
            String age,
            Boolean found,
            Boolean help,
            Set<Med> med,
            String history,
            String video,
            String color,
            String home,
            Category category,
            Gender gender,
            Character character,
            Size size,
            Wool wool,
            Shelter shelter
    ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.found = found;
        this.help = help;
        this.med = med;
        this.history = history;
        this.video = video;
        this.color = color;
        this.home = home;
        this.category = category;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.character = character;
        this.size = size;
        this.wool = wool;
        this.shelter = shelter;
    }
}
```

Med:

```
public enum Med {
    CHIPPED("chipped"),
    VACCINATED("vaccinated"),
    STERILIZED("sterilized"),
    VET_PASSPORT("vet_passport"),
    TREATED_FOR_PARASITES("treated_for_parasites");

    private String med;

    Med(String med) {
        this.med = med;
    }

    public String getMed() {
        return med;
    }
}
```

PetRepository:

```
public interface PetRepository extends JpaRepository<Pet, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Pet> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Pet p WHERE (lower(p.name) LIKE %:text%)")
    Page<Pet> findByName(@Param("text") String text, Pageable pageable);

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Pet p ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT :count")
    List<Pet> findRandomPets(@Param("count") Integer count);
}
```

1. 

```
SELECT id, name, med, size
from pet
          inner join pet_med pm on pet.id = pm.pet_id
where size = 'SMALL';
```

Such a query will work fine and give the result.

2)

```
SELECT id, name, med
from pet
     inner join pet_med pm on pet.id = pm.pet_id
where med = 'VACCINATED';
```

This query will not return any results.